# jquery post still goes through inspite of asp.net mvc 4 validation failure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want an asp.net mvc form to post to a controller and also show a message on error or success, all of which using jquery. I want this jquery post to happen only if the form validation is successful. The validation should be client side before the post to the server happens. The problem is that the post happens even when the form validation has failed. It also looks like the entire form is posting back, but I cant be sure of that. I am using Data annotations in the mvc framework to validate. Here is the code

**View**

```
@model jQueryPosts.Models.ModelVM
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
    @using ( Html.BeginForm("jQueryPost", "Home",null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="FormPost" }))
    { 
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name) 
        <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName) 
        <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Age) 
        <br />

    <input type=submit value="submit" />
    }
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#FormPost').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //This line will prevent the form from submitting
            alert('ajax post here');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $('#FormPost').attr('action'),
                data: $('#FormPost').serialize(),
                accept: 'application/json',
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                    alert('error: ' + xhr.responseText + '-' + error);

                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('resp: ' + response);
                }
            });
        });


    });

 </script>
```

**The Controller**

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult jQueryPost(ModelVM vm)
    {
        ModelVM _vm = vm;

        try
        {
            //some code here
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 406; // Or any other proper status code.
            Response.Write("Custom error message");
            return null;
        }

        return Json("name posted was: " + _vm.Name);
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace JQ.Example
{
    public class ModelVM
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter first name") ]
        public string Name { get; set; }
           [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
           [Required]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code of model with Data annotations.

Comment: added the model class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it happens since when you press input type of submit the form will be submit anyway, just try to add return false to your jquery function

```
$('#FormPost').submit(function (e) {            
        var validated = $("#FormPost").valid();
        if(validated)
        {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('#FormPost').attr('action'),
            data: $('#FormPost').serialize(),
            accept: 'application/json',
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                alert('error: ' + xhr.responseText + '-' + error);

            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert('resp: ' + response);
            }
         });
        }

        return false;
    });
```

add this line of code to controller

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  ...
}
else
{
   ModelState.AddModelError("key", "messege");
}
```

Comment: Should still validate on the server side, though.

Comment: yea. can anything be done about it getting validated on the server as well? looks like it isnt.